# Update axios.get / refresh axios.get / get new record after add it on same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-hooks, axios

I need to get a new record immediately after inserted new record with axios.post.
I've tried axios.get after post but never got the newest record

```
const [listF,setListFin] = useState([])
const [fLen,setLenFin] = useState([])

const addRecord = () => { 
  for(let x = 0; x < kLen; x++){
    Axios.post(mURL+"/api/insert-profilematching", {      
      id_karyawan:id_karyawan,
      kd_kriteria:listK[x].kd_kriteria,
      nilai:s_kriteria[x], //ni nilainya
      s_gap:s_gap,
      bobot_ideal:listK[x].bobot_ideal, 
    }).then((res) => {

    });
  };
  Axios.get(mURL+"/api/list-supertable-cfsf").then((response) => {
    setListFin(response.data)
    setLenFin(response.data.length)      
  }); 
}
console.log(listF)
```

I've tried putting the get request in the .then after post request, and still got nothing

```
const [listF,setListFin] = useState([])
const [fLen,setLenFin] = useState([])

const addRecord = () => { 
  for(let x = 0; x < kLen; x++){
    Axios.post(mURL+"/api/insert-profilematching", {      
      id_karyawan:id_karyawan,
      kd_kriteria:listK[x].kd_kriteria,
      nilai:s_kriteria[x], //ni nilainya
      s_gap:s_gap,
      bobot_ideal:listK[x].bobot_ideal, 
    }).then((res) => {
      Axios.get(mURL+"/api/list-supertable-cfsf").then((response) => {
        setListFin(response.data)
        setLenFin(response.data.length)      
      }) 
    });
  };
}
console.log(listF)
```

I need to get the new record inserted the moment i insert it but the get request is still in the same function.
Appreciate any clues or help.

Comment: Where do `kLen`, `id_karyawan`, `listK`, etc come from? Are you wanting to perform the GET request after each POST or after all of them complete? Is there anything useful in the response to the POST request?

Comment: Sorry it's my first time asking in stack overflow, it's not the full code. I mean the point is the post request is working fine, it's just the get response not working. I want to get the GET request after all the POST is complete. I post the POST request into the same table that I want to get the GET request from. and the record is successfully added, but I can't get the new record that was just added (after the POST request). the get request is show the record but the newest record that just inserted is not showed up

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the response to the POST requests. A lot of APIs will respond with the record created. If yours does too, you won't even need to make an extra GET request

Comment: nothing useful in the response for POST request. the POST request is working fine, I just need to GET request after the all the POST requests been made. I've tried the async and wait, using setTimeout too, and I still cannot get the newest record with GET request. I need to GET request because I need to use the latest record that is inserted for further operation.

Comment: So what _is_ in the response? How do you know it's not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options...

If your API responds to the POST requests with the newly created record, you don't need to make any extra GET requests.

Instead, collect the responses into an array and set them into your state once [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) complete.

```js
const addRecord = async () => {
  const allResponses = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(
      { length: kLen },
      async (_, x) =>
        (
          await Axios.post(`${mURL}/api/insert-profilematching`, {
            id_karyawan,
            kd_kriteria: listK[x].kd_kriteria,
            nilai: s_kriteria[x],
            s_gap,
            bobot_ideal: listK[x].bobot_ideal,
          })
        ).data
    )
  );

  setListFin(allResponses);
};
```

---

Otherwise, use similar code to wait for all the POST requests to complete, then make your GET request

```js
const addRecord = async () => {
  await Promise.all(
    Array.from({ length: kLen }, (_, x) =>
      Axios.post(`${mURL}/api/insert-profilematching`, {
        id_karyawan,
        kd_kriteria: listK[x].kd_kriteria,
        nilai: s_kriteria[x],
        s_gap,
        bobot_ideal: listK[x].bobot_ideal,
      })
    )
  );

  setListFin((await Axios.get(`${mURL}/api/list-supertable-cfsf`)).data);
};
```

I see no point in storing the length separately in either case since you can always get it from `listF.length`.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, I really like the first method concept and it works with different code but the same concept, why am I not just insert it into an array? Thx for enlightening me. And thank you for simplifying my code in many ways. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Better use `async await` to handle promises as follows.

```
const [listF,setListFin] = useState([])
const [fLen,setLenFin] = useState([])

const async addRecord = () => { 
  
    for(let x = 0; x < kLen; x++){
    await Axios.post(mURL+"/api/insert-profilematching", {      
      id_karyawan:id_karyawan,
      kd_kriteria:listK[x].kd_kriteria,
      nilai:s_kriteria[x], //ni nilainya
      s_gap:s_gap,
      bobot_ideal:listK[x].bobot_ideal, 
    })
  };

  const getRes = await Axios.get(mURL+"/api/list-supertable-cfsf");
  
  setListFin(getRes.data)
  setLenFin(getRes.data.length)   
}

console.log(listF)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response, i'll let you know if it works or not